# How to convert application/json to text/csv charset=utf-8 at my tensorflow's endpoint response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to do model quality monitoring for my tensorflow model using aws sagemaker model monitor. At the data capture end where my endpoint request which is my input is in text/csv format where as my response is in json format `{"predictions":[[0.8],[0.5]]}`. I referred the example in [aws_sagemakermodel monitoring_for_tensorflow](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_model_monitor/tensorflow/SageMaker-Model-Monitor-tensorflow.html) where a preprocessing script is added at the place of `create_monitoring_schedule` which converts everything into application/jsonl format. According to the API's `create_monitoring_schedule` description it supports only two format Tabular (text/csv) and JSONL (application/jsonl). Is there a possible way to convert my endpoints output to `text/csv charset: utf-8` that is from `{"predictions":[[0.8],[0.5]]}` to `"0.8,0.5 ..."`?

And when I altered both my input and output using serializer and deserializer to json. Where my ground truth merger got successful executed but my monitoring job got failed with the following attached error `img1` using preprocessing script.

[image]

Same problem in case of data and model quality monitoring with batch transform, as my inference is of this format `{"predictions":[[0.8],[0.5],[0.76] ...}`. Jsonpath is added instead of index at `create_monitoring_schedule` and the jsonpath is`$["predictions"]` at probability attribute , where as in this case my monitoring job is on schedule but its not getting invoked at my processing job end; which part have I missed?

Comment: The Amazon SageMaker Model Monitor container only works with tabular or flattened JSON structures, like {“prediction0”: 1.0, “prediction1” : 2.1}. You could use a preprocessing script to transform the array into the correct JSON structure.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-pre-and-post-processing.html#model-monitor-pre-processing-script

Have you tried to write the pre-processing script to get the data in the correct format?

Comment: Yes I've tried that method it works for **data quality monitoring** but it **isn't** working for model quality monitoring the preprocessing script which I've used for model quality monitoring  is [preprocessing script](https://textdoc.co/udqP2i0cpyEDoZsM) and on trying this I'm getting these errors https://freeimage.host/i/pL7yc7
https://freeimage.host/i/pL7pFS
https://freeimage.host/i/pLY9S9
https://freeimage.host/i/pL7bP2

Comment: I suggest opening a Technical Support case : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/case-management.html